# Set up the parent div take height as children

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I was trying to set the `parent height` as how much height of children, but something is failing.

```css
#parent {
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="parent" style="clear: both; z-index:2;padding: 1rem 1rem;border-radius: 1.25rem;" class="py-2 shadow">
  <div id="child" class="d-flex justify-content-center position-absolute">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning - here applied via the `position-absolute` class - takes an element out of the normal layout flow; it can not influence the height of its parent any more.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0):

For height parent = max height with of all children you can use:

```
height: max-content;
```

but in your code you use absolute so it can not influence the height of parent